# how to display the result from my bison parser in an abstract syntax tree.

Tags: graphviz, abstract-syntax-tree

the parse return the result of arithmetic expression. I need to to be able to display this expression and result using an abstract syntax tree. I am new to flex and bison.

Comment: Does bison generate AST? Or, does it generate parse tree?

Answer (score 0):

You could just print the tree as an [s-expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S-expression).  This is very easy to do.

How:  Execute Visit(Root,0).

```
Visit(node N, D)
{   For i=1 to D print " ";
    Print "(", type(N)), newline
    For i=1 to #Children(N)
       Visit(NthChild(N,i),D+1)
    Print ")", newline 
}
```

This will produce the tree as text output.

To do with this with GraphViz, do the same recursive walk.  Generate node descriptions
on entry to to Visit.  Generate Arc descriptions on each call to Visit.